# Platform for c++ cross compile application

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

Currently, we are using MS Visual Studio and .NET to develop out applications on Window. We are in the process of porting the application to other OS (Linux, Android...etc) and want to get rid of MS Visual Studio and .NET stuff (they have been a pain to work with).

Is there any good development platform that you would recommend?

Thanks,

ABS

Comment: Of course it's my personal opinion, but VS is still one of the best IDE, don't expect to easily reduce your pain :)

Answer (score 3):

I would port the Visual Studio's solution/project files to [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) (in the [downloads list](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) you can get binaries for Windows and Linux), which allows you to generate project files for different platforms, allowing *cross-toolset* development. Eg:

On Windows, running CMake would detect Visual Studio and would generate solution and project files accordingly.

On Linux: running CMake would find, for instance, gcc or g++ and would generate [makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) accordingly.

I have not tried it, but for android's NDK there's this: [android-cmake](https://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/)

[**UPDATE** Information on `gcc/make` for windows]

If you want to drop Visual Studio completely, you can try to set up the `gcc/make` toolchain for Windows with [MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows](http://www.mingw.org/), and port your solution/project files to makefiles.

Comment: I agree, CMake is fantastic!!

Comment: I just installed MinGW, but how do i port the MS visual studio project to makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Moving from Windows to other OS'es may shock you at first, but with time you'll get used to it: You do not need a "platform" or "IDE" per se.
What you will need, is cmake, gcc/g++, a decent text editor and perhaps a debugger frontend.
Optionally you may find ctags useful, Doxygen, an svn repo and a profiler (such as Valgrind/KCachegrind).

I am unaware of how exactly you can port .net stuff to C/C++ (other than re-writing from scratch).

Linux and OSX have many similarities, so porting from one to another should not be that hard. Android is a different story, although C++ for android has become a possibility.

The closest thing to what you are looking for, would probably be Eclipse or Netbeans, but again, the simpler you keep those things, the better IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

As to getting rid of .NET, If your .NET code base is not in managed C++ in its entirety, I would try out **Mono/Xamarin** with **Xamarin Studio IDE** first before embarking on a full port of .NET code base to standardized C++.